# A function which will determine that if a passed in list follows an A B pattern

Tags: list, scheme, racket, lambda

```
(define fun4

 (lambda ( ls)

(cond ((null? ls ) #f)

 (cons (((eqv? 'a (car ls))) && ((eqv? 'b (cdr ls)))))

(else (pattern2 cdr ls)))))
```

In this it showing error - procedure application: expected procedure, given: #t (no arguments), 
What is the erroe in my code. Is logic is fine ???

Comment: There's an `else` but I don't see the `if`... Further, what is `A B` pattern ?

Comment: Its scheme.. Dr. Scheme. in this cond is used as ifelse statment and A B pattern is the pattern of a list that repeated like (A B A B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many errors in your solution. Let's see what's wrong in each of the conditions:

1. The base case of the recursion (empty list) is wrong: an empty list is the exit of the recursion, and it means that the list was traversed correctly and it follows the pattern
2. Another base case is missing: what if the list has a single element?
3. If the pattern doesn't hold, we must return `#f` immediately, and notice how we use `cadr` for accessing the second element, because `&&` doesn't work in Scheme, you must use `and` for the logical *and* operation. Also you have unnecessary, erroneous parentheses surrounding each test (by the way: those were the ones causing the "expected procedure" error)
4. Only if none of the above conditions hold we advance the recursion, and we do so by moving *two* elements further down the list using `cddr`. Also you must call `fun4` to advance the recursion, not `pattern2`

This is the correct way to solve the problem, notice how the above issues were addressed:

```
(define fun4
  (lambda (ls)
    (cond ((null? ls) #t)                                       ; 1
          ((null? (cdr ls)) #f)                                 ; 2
          ((not (and (eq? 'a (car ls)) (eq? 'b (cadr ls)))) #f) ; 3
          (else (fun4 (cddr ls))))))                            ; 4
```

Always test your procedures, the above will work correctly:

```
(fun4 '())
=> #t
(fun4 '(a))
=> #f
(fun4 '(a b))
=> #t
(fun4 '(a b a))
=> #f
(fun4 '(a b a b))
=> #t
```

As a final note, if the empty list is not supposed to follow the pattern, then check for it before calling `fun4` and return `#f` if the initial input list is empty.

Comment: Thanks alot Oscar Lopez.. Great Solution

Answer (score 0):

```
(define fun 
  (lambda (ls)
    (cond ((null? ls) #t)
          ((and (eq? (car ls) 'a)       ; the first item is a
                (list? (cdr ls))        ; the rest of the list
                (not (null? (cdr ls)))  ; which is not null
                (eq? (cadr ls) 'b)      ; and it starts with b
                (fun (cddr ls))) #t)    ; and the rest of the expression is 
          (else #f))))                  ; also in the A B format
```

Running:

```
> (fun '(a b a b))
#t
> (fun '(a b a))
#f
> (fun '(a b))
#t
> (fun '(a))
#f
> (fun '())
#t
>
```

Comment: The cdr of a list is not the second item, but the rest of the list. The cadr is the second item of a list.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor  1. There's no contradiction here: the second item is the "rest of the list". 2. if I didn't know that - why would I check if `(list? (cdr ls))` ? ;) 3. I changed the wording to prevent misunderstanding

Comment: The _code_ was right, but the original comments said "the second item is a list \ which is not null \ and it starts with b \ and the rest of the expression is also in the A B format" which would describe lists of the form `([A (B . _)]*)`, e.g., `(A (B C) A (B . X) A (B (G H)))`, which would not be correct.   As I said, the _code_ was right;  it was only the comments that were misleading.  Typical aliases include `(define second cadr)` and `(define rest cdr)`, but _not_ `(define second cdr)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor since you insist: `cons` is defined as a tuple with `car` as the first item and `cdr` as the second item. `cdr` is defined in a recursive manner. So you can refer to the second item as "rest of the list" which is true. I referred to it as "the second item" which is also true. I changed the wording since you didn't understand what I wrote and I want my comments (as well as the code) to be as clear as possible. That doesn't mean that what I wrote was wrong.

Comment: I understood what you meant but, based on the OP's code (and in general on Stack Overflow) _other_ readers might not have as much experience in Lisp.  It's my _opinion_ (and this is a matter of opinions) that when writing a function that handles lists "second" suggests the "second element of the list" rather than "the second part of a cons cell (which, incidentally are used to encode lists)." I think that this aligns well with a casual description of the task "check whether a list's first element is A, its second element is B, and the rest of the list after that has the same form."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor when you think in a "functional program manner" it's very natural to treat the second element as "rest" or vice verse. Anyways, I do agree with you that some people might not understand it well and that's why I accepted your remark and changed the code-comment ;)

Comment: I did see the edit, and I like it :).  I would posit that the important think in "thinking functionally" when working with an intensional datatype like a list in Lisp though is understanding what the _intended_ method of recursion is for the structure.  With a cons, from which cells are built up, the components are the left and right sides, aka `car` and `cdr`, and the constructor is `cons`.  With a list, there are two constructors:  the empty list and a function that takes an element (the first element of the list) and a list (the rest of the list), which happens to also be called `cons`.

Comment: When writing functions that are supposed to recurse through trees, it makes sense to talk about the `car` and `cdr` as first and second or as left and right, but when writing functions that are supposed to recurse through trees, it makes sense to talk about the `car` and `cdr` as first and rest or as head and tail.  The intention behind it is different, though the code is incidentally the same, so using the terminology that most closely matches the intention becomes important, especially for less experienced users who are still forming their mental models of the language and data structures.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor agreed! also, another approach which might make it clearer (instead of changing the comment) would be to use `pair?` instead of `list?` :)

Comment: Thanks alot Alfasin.. grt solution.

Answer (score 0):

So much wheel reinvention. Just use SRFI 1!

```
(require srfi/1)
(define (fun4 lst)
  (every eq? lst (circular-list 'a 'b)))
```

(This operates under the assumption that `(a b a)` should be valid rather than invalid.)